# Rails optional /:locale route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, internationalization, routes

I'm trying to setup a routing system for my rails app that allows for an optional route (/:locale) to be allowed to the base of the website.

So more or less:

/en/home/ would goto the same page as /home/
/en/people/ -> /people/

The only issue I'm having is setting this up in the routes config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `scope '(:locale)' do`...`end`.  You can see an example from [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) here:

http://intertwingly.net/projects/AWDwR4/checkdepot-30/section-15.1.html

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do is, in `config/routes.rb`:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|fr/ do
    #here only two languages are accepted: english and french

  end
end
```

And in my `ApplicationController`:

```
before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || "en"
end
```

Comment: why not to use `I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale`?