# Default params in urls when using scopes with Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I know this has been asked already, but still I can't make it work.
I'm trying to get the `:locale` parameter to show by using `default_url_options`, like this:

```
# SomethingController < ApplicationController
def default_url_options(options={})
  { :locale => I18n.locale }
end
```

`I18n.locale` is set with a `before_filter` and has the correct value (debugged with pry).
The routes:

```
# In routes
scope "(:locale)", :defaults => { :locale => I18n.default_locale } do
  get "something" => "something#index", :as => :something_index
end
```

In my view I tried:

```
url_for :something_index
```

and

```
something_index_url
```

but they both return "/something" instead of "/en/something". Is there something else I have to do in order to automatically get the parameter to show?

I read about this [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params):

> Every helper method dependent on url_for (e.g. helpers for named
>   routes like root_path or root_url, resource routes like books_path or
>   books_url, etc.) will now automatically include the locale in the
>   query string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could amend the get matcher:

```
scope :locale, :defaults => { :locale => I18n.default_locale } do
  get "/:locale/something" => "something#index", :as => :something_index
end
```

For a better method, refer here:

[Rails optional /:locale route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636140/rails-optional-locale-route)

Comment: Just updated answer, it is because you are using `"(:locale)"` instead of just `:locale`.

Comment: You're right, a locale is shown now, but it's always the default locale. (`:defaults => { :locale => I18n.default_locale }`)

Comment: You need to set the locale when passing in the link. 'something_index_path(locale: 'fr')'. What I'd do here is wrap the links in my own helper. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: Updated my answer to refer to a similar question which will help you.

Comment: I'm not sure it's clear what I'm trying to do, I have updated my question with a link to the Rails guide.